Pull request with Squash Commit in Azure DevOps
I'm experiencing an issue with squash commits in Azure DevOps pull requests. Occasionally, when I complete a pull request using the squash commit option, not all changes/changed files seem to be included in the squash. This results in some changes appearing to be missing from the final commit.
Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, do you know why this happens or how to ensure all files are included in the squash?
Here are some details about my setup:
I’m using Azure DevOps for version control.
The issue doesn't occur consistently; sometimes all changed files are included, other times they are not.
I've checked for any error messages or logs but haven't found anything unusual.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

It took at the end only one commit


are you sure you mean "commits" and not "changes" or "changed files"? Because in your pictures I see changed files and one changed file, not multiple commits and one commit...

yeah basically he should merge all those files you can see in the first pictures, as a squash commit
But Azure Devops merged only one file as you can see in the second picture

Aha, just like I thought: some changes/changed files seem to be ignored, not "some commits". I suggested an Edit for this.

Please make sure you are comparing the pull request with the corresponding squash merge commit.
For example, I have a pull request ID 61 from bug to main branch.

After I complete the Pull request with Squash Commit, the commit is in the main branch history with pull request ID 61.

Open the commit, you can find the pull request ID in the page. Please compare the files here.

In your second screenshot, the pull request ID is not there. It seems the commit is not from a squash merge.
